# Terraform is successful but I can not find resource

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to setup my AWS EKS cluster via terraform and I'm having issues with creating resources within the EKS cluster. My cluster is created and I was able to create node groups using `aws_eks_node_group`. However, when I attempt to create `kubernetes_daemonset` and `kubernetes_namespace` the terraform is successful and says that the resources were created, but I do not see them in the console. I can view the node groups in this cluster and when I route to another cluster I can view the namespaces and daemonsets, so it's not a permissions issue.

Terraform output

```
[docker] [deploy-terraform] [terraform apply] kubernetes_namespace.jupyterhub: Creation complete after 0s [id=jupyterhub]
```

```
[docker] [deploy-terraform] [terraform apply] kubernetes_daemon_set_v1.example: Creation complete after 0s [id=kube-system/nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-0.9.0]
```

TF resources

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    command     = "aws"
    args = [
      "eks",
      "get-token",
      "--cluster-name",
      data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
    ]
  }

}

resource "kubernetes_daemonset" "nvidia-device-plugin" {
  metadata {
    name      = "nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-0.9.0"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
  spec {
    selector {
      match_labels = { name : "nvidia-device-plugin-ds" }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          name = "nvidia-device-plugin-ds"
        }
      }
      spec {
        toleration {
          key      = "nvidia.com/gpu"
          operator = "Exists"
          effect   = "NoSchedule"
        }
        toleration {
          key      = "hub.jupyter.org/dedicated"
          operator = "Exists"
          effect   = "NoSchedule"
        }
        container {
          image = "nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:v0.9.0"
          name  = "nvidia-device-plugin-ctr"
          security_context {
            allow_privilege_escalation = false
            capabilities {
              drop = ["ALL"]
            }
          }

          volume_mount {
            name       = "device-plugin"
            mount_path = "/var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins"
          }

        }
        volume {
          name = "device-plugin"
          host_path {
            path = "/var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins"
          }
        }
        affinity {
          node_affinity {
            required_during_scheduling_ignored_during_execution {
              node_selector_term {
                match_expressions {
                  key      = "beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type"
                  operator = "In"
                  values   = ["p2.xlarge"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "jupyterhub" {
  metadata {
    name = "jupyterhub"
    labels = {
      name = "jupyterhub"
    }
  }
}

``
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not have the `manage_aws_auth_configmap` boolean set to true in the eks module.